# how to make a jbutton thats check if the number hexidecimal, binary,octal, decimal?

Tags: java

Im very new to java, newbee in short. I want to make a program that checks if the number is hexidecimal, binary, octal, decimal. And if its Hexdecimal/binary/octal convert it to decimal but if it is a decimal not convert it. in my case i made a jbutton that if its clicked it will first check the number then convert it to decimal if it is not a decimal. Now the problem is i don't know what to add to my code, at present i can only check if it is a hexidecimal and then convert it to decimal if it meets the requirements and if not it will just stay. here is my code.

```
       private void del1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent 
           evt) {                                     
           String hex=prime1.getText();
           long dec=0;
         int r=0,c=0,b,con,er; 
      con=(int)Math.round(inb);
         String co2, tra=prime1.getText();
        boolean valid;       
       if(valid=true){for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++ ) {
              int digit = hexValue( hex.charAt(i) );
               if (digit == -1) {
                  return; 
                     }dec = 16*dec + digit;
        prime1.setText(String.valueOf(dec));          
          }
           static int hexValue(char ch) {
          switch (ch) {
          case '0':
           return 0;
          case '1':
           return 1;
          case '2':
          return 2;
          case '3':
          return 3;
          case '4':
           return 4;
          case '5':
          return 5;
          case '6':
          return 6;
          case '7':
           return 7;
          case '8':
         return 8;
         case '9':
         return 9;
         case 'a':     // Note:  Handle both upper and lower case letters.
         case 'A':
         return 10;
         case 'b':
         case 'B':
         return 11;
         case 'c':
         case 'C':
         return 12;
         case 'd':
         case 'D':
         return 13;
         case 'e':
         case 'E':
         return 14;
         case 'f':
         case 'F':
          return 15;
          default:
          return -1;
            }
          }  // end hexValue
```

here prime1 is a jtextfield.

Comment: There is no difference in octal, decimal and hexadecimal for certain cases. You can not distinguish them.

Comment: How are you going to distinguish hexadecimal, decimal, octal, and binary numbers?   For example, what kind of number `101` is for you?

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly, this should be what you are looking for:

```
int getBaseAndConvertToDecimal(String input) {

            int output = -1;
            for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
                if(Character.isAlphabetic(input.charAt(i)) && Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(i))<='F') {
                    output = 16;
                }
                else {
                    if(Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i)) && Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)))>=8) {
                        output = 10;
                    }
                    else {
                        if(Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i)) && Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)))>=2) {
                            output = 8;
                        }
                        else {
                            if(input.charAt(i)=='0' || input.charAt(i)=='1') {
                                output = 2;
                            }
                            else {
                                output = -1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(output != -1) {
                //int this case, the output object represents the base of the input string
                //Integer.parseInt(inputToConvert, destinationBase);
                return Integer.parseInt(input, output);
            }
            return output;
        }
```